# Alternative to the Pluto library for serializing suspended coroutines in Lua?

Tags: lua, coroutine

I'm using the [Pluto library](https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto), but it requires an older version of Lua (5.1.3), and it has bugs with serializing suspended coroutines. Are there alternatives out there?

Comment: Doesn't it work with Lua 5.1.4, which is the current version? (Lua 5.2 has not been released yet.)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even work with Lua 5.1.3; at least coroutine serialization doesn't: https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto/issues/6  Basic table serialization probably does, but there are 2 dozen ways to do that...

Comment: If you read down further theres recent comments that seem to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, those are my comments. The luarocks version of Pluto is broken, but this works: https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This branch of Pluto](https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto) works properly - but you can't use Lua 5.2.

I haven't discovered any alternatives.